# C++ Member Vector Inaccurate Values

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, file-io

I've created a class called "Person" which holds a name, three sets of high scores and a picture link. I am reading from a text file that contains all of these variables and create several "Person" objects accordingly,then put them into a vector of "Person" objects.

This is the function that takes in an empty vector and outputs a vector with Persons added.

```
void input_data(vector<Person>& input){
  ifstream ifs("personData.txt");
  while (true) {
    if (ifs.eof()) {
      return;
    }
    Person n;   
    string name;
    string picture;
    string check;
    int t1;int t2;int t3;
    int r1;int r2;int r3;
    int f1;int f2;int f3;
    getline(ifs,name);  // use getline to deal with spaces 
    getline(ifs,picture); // use getline to deal with spaces
    ifs >> t1 >> t2 >> t3;
    ifs >> r1 >> r2 >> r3;
    ifs >> f1 >> f2 >> f3;
    ifs.ignore(100, '\n');
    getline(ifs,check); // use getline to deal with spaces
    n.setName(name);
    n.setPic(picture);
    n.addScore(3, t1);n.addScore(3, t2);n.addScore(3, t3);
    n.addScore(4, r1);n.addScore(4, r2);n.addScore(4, r3);
    n.addScore(5, f1);n.addScore(5, f2);n.addScore(5, f3);
    input.push_back(n);
    if(check == ""){
        cout << endl << "breaking" << endl;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, using the "addScore" function, I intend to change the vector of scores in each Person according to the inputted type (3, 4 , or 5). Here is the Person class that is use. The logic for adding the values to the vector is used to maintain a size of 3 in each vector, and so I add the new value to the vector, sort it, and then delete the smallest entry. This gives me tht top three high scores.

```
class Person{
    private:
        //basic member functions
        string name;
        string pic;
        vector<int> highThree;
        vector<int> highFour;
        vector<int> highFive;
    public:
        //constructor jsut makes eveything zero
        Person(string m_name = "", string m_pic = ""):
            name(m_name), 
            pic(m_name),
            //initializing every vector to three instnace of 0
            highThree(3,0),
            highFour(3,0),
            highFive(3,0){}
        //manipulating member functionsjj
        void setName(string i_name){name = i_name;}
        string getName(){return name;}
        void setPic(string i_pic){pic = i_pic;}
        string getPic(){return pic;}
        //logic for adding to the highschores

        void addScore(int gameType, int val){
            //(which is sorted), then add it and sort it again
            if (gameType == 3){
                //name = "yo";
                highThree.push_back(val);
                //sort the vector
                sort(highThree.begin(), highThree.end());
                //erase the first thing
                highThree.erase(highThree.begin());
            }
            if (gameType == 4){
                highFour.push_back(val);
                sort(highFour.begin(), highFour.end());
                highFour.erase(highThree.begin());
            //cout << val << endl;
            }
            if (gameType == 5){
                highFive.push_back(val);
                sort(highFive.begin(), highFive.end());
                highFive.erase(highThree.begin());
            //cout << val << endl;
            }
        }
        //gets the three score vecotors
        vector<int>& getScores(int gameType){
            if (gameType == 3){
                for(int i = 0; i<highThree.size(); i++){
                    cout << highThree[i] << endl;
                }
                return highThree;
            }else if(gameType == 4){
                return highFour;
            }else if(gameType == 5){
                return highFive;
            }else{
                cout << "error in getScores input\n";
                vector<int> bad;
                return bad;
            }
        }

};
```

In main, when I try to access the scores in one of these member vectors, I get results that are not accurate to what I took in from the file. In fact, I printed out my input values in the "addScore" function as well as in the "input_data" function, and they are correct. This means that I'm getting data from the file accurately, but there is something wrong afterword.

```
int main(){
    vector<Person> peeps;
    input_data(peeps);
    //the value that i get below is wrong
    cout << peeps[0].getScores(3)[0];

}
```

The value that I get in the print above is 0, when it should be 8
. The text file that I'm reading from is attached below. I apologize for a such a long post, but I've spoken to all of my team mates about the issue and cant seem to figure out what is going wrong. There seems to be an issue with retrieving the contents of the member vector, but I cant find the issue.

```
bob
mypic
8 9 10
3 4 5
2 7 6
```

Comment: Fyi, `return bad;` in `getScores` returns a reference to an automatic variable that is going to expire long before the caller can do anything with it. You're returning a dangling reference, and using it invokes *undefined behavior*. Your compiler should warn you about this. If it didn't, your warning levels aren't high enough.

Comment: It should return the right value if you replace `highFour.erase(highThree.begin());` by `highFour.erase(highFour.begin());` and `highFive.erase(highThree.begin());` by `highFive.erase(highFive.begin());`. After correction of this copy-paste error and after returning `vector<int>` for `getScores` (without any references), I succeeded in printing the `8` value.

Comment: Thanks Franck, dumb error, much appreciated. Also, for the "return bad;" part, is it best to throw an exception? What is the best alternative?

Comment: @JayK. With a signature like `vector<int> getScores(int gameType) const`, your method is safe since it returns a copy of the variable. Alternatives can be throwing an exception or returning an error message iin an optional argument with a signature like `vector<int>* getScores(int gameType, std::string* errorMessage) const`. All depends on how you want to manage the error at the caller's level.